# How do I find and replace text with regex in Godot?

Tags: godot

The way to find and replace text in javascript from regex is like so:

```
"ab".replace(/./g, (match) => match + "&");
// outputs: a&b&
```

What is the equivalent function or functions in gdscript?

Comment: When I [search for "godot regex"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=godot+regex&ia=web), the first result is [this page from the engine documentation](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_regex.html), which includes information on how to replace text with the `sub` method. What do you need that isn't already documented there?

Comment: The "replace" argument of sub is a string.  I suppose I could achieve a lot of things by using capture groups, but there's also a lot of things I couldn't achieve.  In my case, I need to know what was captured and add it to a dictionary.  I'm doing more than string transformations.

Comment: That would be a good thing to state in your question, then. Use the "edit" link at the bottom to ensure all relevant information is included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Godot we use the `RegEx` class, and it has a `sub` method to replace matches, however it does not take a callback. *`Callable`s are relatively recent addition in Godot, and many APIs has not been updated to use them.* That does not mean we can't do it.

Furthermore, we cannot specify global (`g`) when compiling the `RegEx` (Godot does not support the delimiter and modifier syntax). However the `g` modifier means it will not stop on one match... Which is what `search_all` will do. So we build our code on top of it.

The method `search_all` returns an `Array` of `RegExMatch` from which we can get the start and end indexes of each match... To replace the text we can use `get_slice` and build a new `String` from the pieces (No, Godot does not have an equivalent of `splice`). And since the replacement might not have the same length, the indexes would be wrong after the first replacement... So, we will keep track of an offset to make it work.

This is working Godot 4 code:

```
var subject := "ab"
var pattern := "."
var callback := func(text:String) -> String: return text + "&"

var regex := RegEx.new()
regex.compile(pattern)

var regex_matches := regex.search_all(subject)
var offset := 0
for regex_match in regex_matches:
    var start := regex_match.get_start()
    var end := regex_match.get_end()
    var length := end - start
    var text := subject.substr(start + offset, length)
    var replacement := str(callback.call(text))
    subject = (
        subject.substr(0, start + offset)
        + replacement
        + subject.substr(end + offset)
    )
    offset += replacement.length() - text.length()

prints(subject)
```

Output:

```
a&b&
```

*For Godot 3, we cannot write an inline anonymous method like I did for `callback` above. And Godot 3 didn't have typed `Array`s, so we cannot infer the type of `regex_match` thus some implicit typing won't work (I mean you would have to use `=` instead of `:=`).*

---

**Addendum**:

For your case, you could use a capture group in your pattern (i.e. `"(.)"`) so you can use a backreference in `sub`. Which results in less code - assuming you can express the replacement you want in this form.

This is working code (it should work in both Godot 3 and Godot 4):

```
var subject := "ab"
var pattern := "(.)"

var regex = RegEx.new()
regex.compile(pattern)

subject = regex.sub(subject, "$1&", true)

prints(subject)
```

Output:

```
a&b&
```

Note that I'm passing `true` as third parameter of `sub`, that is telling it to replace all matches, without it the output is `a&b` (i.e. it only replaces the first match).

Answer (score 2):

Based off the awesome answer by @Theraot, here's a utility function which can be added to an autoload script.

```
func str_replace(target: String, regex: RegEx, cb: Callable) -> String:
    var out = ""
    var last_pos = 0
    for regex_match in regex.search_all(target):
        var start := regex_match.get_start()
        out += target.substr(last_pos, start - last_pos)
        out += str(cb.call(regex_match.get_string()))
        last_pos = regex_match.get_end()
        
    out += target.substr(last_pos)
    return out
```

Usage:

```
# outputs: "alad"
print(Globals.str_replace(
    "abcd", 
    RegEx.create_from_string("bc"), 
    func(text: String): return "la"
))
```

Comment: As alternative to using an autoload, you could make it an `static func` and put on a script with a `class_name`.